# Register COM Interop dll using InstallShield

Tags: installshield-2010

I am trying to register COM Interop dlls using Installshield from last 10 days but still found no luck. Here's the issue:

I have an Installscript project with some ActiveX controls and dlls. Now I want to replace some ActiveX with .NET com Interop dlls created on VS2010 using C#.net. I am registering those
com Interop dlls using batch file.

So the Issue is , If VS2010 is installed on the client machine then application works properly but If .NET Framework is Installed on the client machine instead of VS2010 , dlls get registered but application doesn't work and throws an error "Make sure the Object is entered in the system registry".
Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.